# Yeoman/Grunt run Compass with webapp project. Circular argument reference - browsers ERROR

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, compass

I simply want to start a new project with Yeoman including Compass.

Compass works fine if I want a Yeoman SPA so it seems everything is included/installed:

```
yo angular
? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? Yes
```

When I want a webapp (site) I can't get it to work:

```
yo webapp
? What more would you like? Sass, Bootstrap Yes
etc, etc.
```

Server starts fine

```
grunt serve
```

Until I add my new scss file with:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Now has issue connecting?

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "app/styles/custom-base.scss" added.
Running "sass:server" (sass) task
>> file to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3
>> Current dir: /Users/kerrysmyth/code/app/styles/
>>   Line 3  Column 9  app/styles/custom-base.scss
```

Adjusted the Gruntfile.js as described here https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/compass.md

Tried to run grunt serve again

```
grunt serve
```

Now has other problem (circular argument reference - browsers):

```
Warning:
/Users/somebody/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/caniuse.rb:72: warning: circular argument reference - browsers
```

Adjusted the file as described here https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1902 changing:

```
browsers = browsers
```

to

```
browsers = browsers()
```

Try starting the grunt serve

```
grunt serve
```

Again but now not working:

```
Running "serve" task
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.
Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-07-24 01:27:32 UTC)
loading tasks        139ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 18%
loading grunt-babel  475ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 61%
babel:dist           164ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 21%
Total 779ms
    Warning:  Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

The warning does not point to anything & grunt serve wont work.

Really stuck after hours of attempting to remedy this. I feel like putting a pencil up my nose & smashing my head on the desk.